# Converting iso code to name

Tags: location

How can i convert country iso code to country name while creating a node programatically using node_save? I am creating nodes programatically by fetching contents from secondary database of drupal. When i do this way, am getting country iso code in the country field instead want the name of the country. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$name = location_country_name($iso_code);
```

For reference http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21location%21location.inc/function/location_country_name/7

Answer (score 0):

```
$countries = country_get_list();
$country_name = $countries[$country_iso_code]
```

Example: if $country_iso_code is 'ES' then the above will return 'Spain' in $country_name